# Change style of an element by clicking on another element

Tags: html, css

I would like to change background color of a block of text (that is surrounded by other blocks of text) when a link is clicked.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span3 offset1">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
      <li><a href="#item1"> Item 1 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#item2"> Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="span7 test-content">
    <div id="item1">
        <h4> Item 1 Header </h4>
        <p> Item 1 Text</p>
    </div>

    <div id="item2">
        <h4> Item 2 Header</h4>
    <p> Item 2 Text </p>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

When I click on the Item 2 < a> element I would like the background color of Item 2 div to change to highlight it. Then, if I clicked on an < a> element that referenced Item 1, Item 1 div background color would change and Item 2 background color would return to original (white).

What's the easiest way to do this? I can't figure it out with CSS.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Heads up: avoid using `a href=` unless you are wanting to load a new page or scroll down to a particular section. Use `button` or `span` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest, in compliant browsers:

```
p:target {
    background-color : #ffa; /* or whatever you'd prefer */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AY6Kt/).

This is also possible in Internet Explorer, but will require html changes unfortunately. Or JavaScript could be used instead, if that would be preferred.

In reference to the updated posted HTML, I'd adapt the above to the following:

```
/* will highlight the 'div:target' itself: */
div:target {
    background-color: #f90;
}

/* will highlight the descendant 'p' element(s) of the 'div:target': */
div:target p {
    background-color : #ffa;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AY6Kt/3/).

The key is to remember what element takes the `:target` pseudo-class, in this case it's the `div`, rather than the `p` (which is a child of that `div` element).

References:

- [Compatibility for `:target` pseudo-class](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#t44).
- [`:target` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo).

Comment: It didn't seem to work. I've updated the code in my original question to more accurately reflect my code. Even if I insert your code (so it refers to ALL p elements), it doesn't get applied to the p (or the div) when I check it in chrome DOM.

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of help; and thank *you* for accept. =)